# How to split Names SurNames and Short Names using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

Like example, I have these sentences:

1. Kaip direktoriu yra sake V.Adamkus  man reikia kad  perimtu E.Žlabys visa valdyma.
2. Kaip direktoriu yra sake V.A. man reikia kad e.z. (Eimantas Žlabys)  perimtu B.A. visa valdyma.
3. Kaip direktoriu yra sake Valdas Mykolas Brazauskas man reikia kad  perimtu visa valdyma A.B..

and I'm now trying to parse these types of words from sentence:

1. V.Adamkus, E.Žlabys
2. V.A., B.A., A.B.
3. Eimantas Žlabys
4. Valdas Mykolas Brazauskas

I have written regex:

```
 ([A-Ž]{1}\.[A-Ž]{1}\.)|([A-Ž]\s[A-Ž])| ([A-Ž]{1}\.[A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,})
```

But he don't work with **"Eimantas Žlabys"** types of words... where I did the mistake in regex to find that tipe of words? :/

Comment: couldn't you just split with white space?

Comment: No, because these words are in sentence :/

Comment: I 'm really not sure that `A-Ž` does what you think it does.

Comment: if they are in a sentence, then how are you detecting the names?

Comment: SO can't debug the regex issues of everybody...

Answer (score -1):

I do not really like the way this looks but I think this would solve your examples:

```
 ([A-Ž]{1}\.[A-Ž]{1}\.)|([A-Ž]\s[A-Ž])|([A-Ž]{1}\.[A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,}|([A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,}\s[A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,})|([A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,}\s[A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,}\s[A-Ž]{1}[a-ž]{1,}))
```

In fact I think you cannot parse all names with a regex in a reliable way, unless you know for sure the format of all of these names in advance.

Comment: Didn't help :/ I don't know how to write that regex detecs if first letter is upper then in lower letters :(

Comment: Please post your solution so we can compare them.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question, so I wrote example sentences, and what I want found in them :)